# How to check if a directory exists in Ansible playbook level(not in host) from within a role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have 2 ansible roles.

- `rundeck_install`
- `rundeck_app`

`rundeck_install` role install the rundeck community edition. `rundeck_app` role installs `jdk`, `mysql` and `rundeck`(by using the`rundeck_install` role)

`rundeck_install` role has a task to copy all the `*.aclpolicy` files from `rundeck_install/files/aclpolicies` folder.

```yaml
# this will copy aclpolicy files from <role>/files/aclpolicies directory
- name: Copy ACL policy files
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "aclpolicies/"
    dest: /etc/rundeck
    owner: rundeck
    group: rundeck
    mode: 0664
```

I added one additional task in role to copy any `aclpolicy` files that exists in `<parent_role>/files/aclpolicies` directory.
In my case `rundeck_app` including `rundeck_install` role, so if any `aclpolicy` file exists in `rundeck_app/files/aclpolicies` folder I want to copy all those, giving priority over files under `rundeck_install/files/aclpolicies`. For this I added below task after the above one.

```yaml
# this will copy aclpolicy files from <running playbook>/files/aclpolicies directory
- name: Copy ACL policy files from playbook
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/aclpolicies/"
    dest: /etc/rundeck
    owner: rundeck
    group: rundeck
    mode: 0664
```

This is all working fine. But giving error when there is no `aclpolicies` folder under `rundeck_app/files/`.

How can I check if the parent role has the folder and skip running the task?

Answer (score 1):

> I am planning to run a check if the directory exists before executing the task.

Is there a specific reason for that? [Ansible is a Configuration Management Tool](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/configuration-management) which which you [declare a state](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html), ideally [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency).

Therefore, one just need to

```yaml
- name: Make sure target dir exists
  file:
    path: /etc/rundeck
    state: directory
    owner: rundeck
    group: rundeck
    mode: '0664'
```

Ansible will then create it if it not exists, as well correct permissions if they are not correct (anymore).

If a check is necessary the result can be registered and based on that, further actions can be taken.

```yaml
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result
```

The output and variables looks like

```yaml
TASK [Show result] *********************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  result:
    ansible_facts:
      discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python
    changed: true
    diff:
      after:
        mode: '0664'
        path: /etc/rundeck
      before:
        mode: '0755'
        path: /etc/rundeck
    failed: false
    ...
```

and

```yaml
TASK [Show result] *******
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  result:
    changed: false
    diff:
      after:
        path: /etc/rundeck
      before:
        path: /etc/rundeck
    failed: false
    gid: 1234567890
    group: rundeck
    mode: '0664'
    owner: rundeck
    path: /etc/rundeck
    ...
```

**Further Links**

- [`file` – Manage files and file properties](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html)
- [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#examples)

Comment: I want to check if the running playbook have a directory under files, from within a ansible role. While writing the role I don't have any visibility in which playbook it will be included but if the playbook has some aclpolicy files under files/aclpolicies then I want to copy those to remote host.

Comment: The problem is not to check if a directory exists in host, but to know the playbook which included a role have any directory under files.